# "fetchAll" command doesn't work ( Zend Framework ) with long sql query statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, fetchall

I'm trying to send throught "fetchAll" command of zend framework (PHP) a  query to mysql DB.  the query is composed by a large amount of characters (about 9000 characters).
My query is like:  `select * from mytable where name_text like 'bla bla bla....(about 8600 characters)..'`

The result is that the process of my php application becomes in "wait" status (no error, but process doesn't continue), and on mysql db  remains a connection in sleep state.

Note: if I execute the sql statment directly in phpmyadmin it runs, and in few seconds i have the result set.

My system configuration is:
ubuntu 12.10
mysql
apache2
php5

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?
thank you in advance

Comment: is your string escaped properly?

Comment: Can you post your apache logs , I am sure some log entry will be there I feel it is the memory_limit or maximum_execution_time which is giving some problem

Comment: Do you need to be doing a LIKE search given that your string is that long? Presumably you don't have an 8600 character index?

Comment: Hi guys, my string is properly escaped.

Comment: In the apache log file there's: [Fri Feb 22 09:46:30 2013] [notice] child pid 1521 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)